# DataGridViewRow to Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I need to get the data from datagrid for the double clicked row into a new form, i've just dived into dotnet development, please guide the way to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as Gapton said, you need to hand `CellDoubleClick` event and inside this event you can get current row's cell values using following syntax:

```
object cell1 = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value; 
object cell2 = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
```

where `e.RowIndex` is the index of row user double clicked on and `e.ColumnIndex` contains the column index of cell for which this double click is occured...

now, to pass values to new form, you can do this in two different ways:
1: using public properties, say you have Form2 to which you want to pass values, in Form2 class define properties for the values your are interested in such as:

```
public object cell1 { get; set; }
public object cell2 { get; set; }
```

and in your `CellDoubleClick` above, instantiate new object of Form2, assign values to properties and call show method to display this form:

```
private void dataGrid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            object cell1 = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value; 
            object cell2 = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value; 

Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.cell1 = cell1;
...
form2.Show();
        }
```

2: using overloaded constructor, write an overloaded constructor for Form2, like this:

```
public Form2(object cell1, ...) {
this.cell1 = cell1;
....
InitializeComponent();
}
```

and then in event handler:

```
private void dataGrid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            object cell1 = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value; 
            object cell2 = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value; 

Form2 form2 = new Form2(cell1...);
form2.Show();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Waqas for the very detailed, and working explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

In the Events panel you will be able to assign a function to call when a row is double clicked. In the function you can then do DataGridViewRow.Cells[index].Value to access the cells' values then pass it to a new form for whatever purposes.

Alternatively, you can pass the entire DataGridViewRow:
dataGridView1.CurrentRow will give you the DataGridViewRow that is currently selected.